# How do I disable Razor being clever with opening and closing tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In a loop I need to wrap `div`s after first one into mechanism that hides them and shows when expanded, easy right.

```
//above this lives code that draws a product section 
                if (product.DisplayOrder == 1 && Model.Count > 1)
                {
                    <div class="arrow-with-text" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                        <div class="arrow-down" style="display: none"></div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 2em;margin-top: -1.3em;font-size: 1.2em;color: #2280c4;">Other available Wills…</div>
                    </div>
                <div class="other-wills" style="display: none">
                }
                else (product.DisplayOrder == Model.Count)
                {
                    </div>
                }
```

What I expected was all sections that go after first being wrapped in `other-wills` div and then being closed on last one. What it actually get's rendered to is this.

```
                        <div class="arrow-with-text" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                        <div class="arrow-down" style="display: none"></div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 2em;margin-top: -1.3em;font-size: 1.2em;color: #2280c4;">Other available Wills…</div>
                    </div>
                <div class="other-wills" style="display: none">
                }
                else (product.DisplayOrder == Model.Count)
                {
                    </div>
<div class="sections-wrapper">
```

which isn't exactly what I expected (it reendered `}else product.DisplayOrder == Model.Count){` as text).

[image]

**How do I make razor interpret my closing of `if` statement and `else` correctly?**

Comment: tried `@else` and `@if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.Raw("</div>")
```

and

```
@Html.Raw("<div class=\"your-class\">")
```

for the 'stray' dynamic divs

Comment: Did work, thanks. It is surprising that I still had to use `@Html.Raw` (not `Html.Raw`) while in razor code section. Html.Raw wouldn't throw the error simply would not render anything at all.

Comment: I always think of the @Html.xxxxx as the equivalent to "Response.Write" or "echo" even if you're in a Razor area. Omitting the @ symbol would be used if you were assigning the resulting HTML to a variable within Razor code.